# Integração entre Console Application, WebService e Frontend Web C#

Tags: c#, web-service, front-end, back-end

Estou desenvolvendo meu TCC e preciso de orientação de qual a melhor maneira fazer algumas partes do sistema.

**Descrição:**

É um sistema para otimização de uso de laboratórios. Tal sistema deverá ter *frontend web* no lado cliente e um *web service* no lado servidor.

**Frontend -** sistema simples que deverá ter uma lista de laboratórios e algumas informações, tais informações devem ser enviadas ao servidor através do serviço web. O *frontend* também deverá ter um botão "RUN", que deverá se comunicar ao serviço web do lado servidor, o servidor irá executar o algoritmo de otimização e retornar a resposta ao *frontend* para ser exibido ao usuário.

**Servidor -** deverá ter uma *rest API* (ou similar) para comunicação com o *frontend*. Já tenho pronto uma DLL com a definição das classes do sistema, *datacontext* para *entityframework* e algoritmo de otimização implementado.
O lado servidor deverá rodar o algoritmo de otimização em horários pré-definidos e quando se clica no botão "RUN" no *frontend*.

Problemas quq venho enfrentando:

1. Não sei como fazer com que o botão "RUN" gere uma ação (rodar o
   algoritmo) no lado servidor.
2. Não sei como fazer com que o método rode o algoritmo em horários
   específicos no lado servidor.

Pensei em implementar uma máquina de estados (como console *application*) no servidor para fazer esse controle de quando rodar o algoritmo. Mas não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer isso.

Estou aberto a possíveis soluções para esses problemas em específico, ou até mesmo mudar a arquitetura do sistema.

A única coisa que não posso deixar de utilizar é a DLL com as classes e métodos para o algoritmo, mas posso fazer pequenas modificações nela.

Comment: No seu lado do front-end, você esta trabalhando com qual tecnologia javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi exatamente sua dúvida, mas vamos lá.

Primeiro ponto:

**1-Não sei como fazer com que o botão "RUN" gere uma ação (rodar o algoritmo) no lado servidor.**

**Resposta:** Você pode implementar no servidor um WebService, ao clicar no botão Run a View irá chamar uma ação no Backend que deverá consumir o WebService e retornar o resultado do seu algoritmo para o Frontend.

**2-Não sei como fazer com que o método rode o algoritmo em horários específicos no lado servidor.**

**Resposta**: Essa pergunta me deixou um pouco confuso porque não entendi o que o algoritmo irá executar de tempo em tempo, mas se for algo como atualizar informações, creio que você poderia criar uma aplicação Console mesmo.

Utilize o próprio agendador do seu S.O para controlar a execução de tempo em tempo, visto que a maioria dos Sistemas Operacionais implementam esse tipo de serviço e ainda proporcionam uma boa estabilidade, como verificar se tem rede para executar a rotina, caso ocorra algum erro persistir ect, isso pode te poupar um pouco de trabalho.

Obs: Deixe sua dúvida um pouco mais clara e tentarei te ajudar na medida do possível.

---

Segue um exemplo de como chamar essa ação pela View

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index")'" />
```

Lembre-se que em MVC as páginas não são mapeadas como em Web Forms, MVC trabalha com o conceito que toda URL chama uma ação, que pode ou não retornar uma View.

Nesse Exemplo tentei ser o mais simplista possível inclusive utilizando a **WebClient** por ser mais simples, visto que sua dúvida era em como chamar a ação.

Construí um Ws onde ele me retorna um vetor de Strings no formato Json, recupero o Valor do Ws e apresento na View.

//Controller

```
public ActionResult SuaView()
    {

        WebClient cli = new WebClient();

        string jsonRetur = cli.DownloadString("http://localhost:54119/api/default/consulta");

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var retorno = js.Deserialize<string[]>(jsonRetur);


        return View(retorno);
    }
```

Na View eu tratei o retorno assim:

//Minha View que foi criada unicamente para exibir os valores recebidos e nada mais

```
@model string[]
@foreach(string nome in Model)
{
   @nome @Html.Raw("<br />");

}
```

Espero ter te ajudado, caso tenha uma dúvida mais específica com a implementação, crie um tópico e seja o mais objetivo possível que tentarei te ajudar na implementação.

Comment: ponto 1 - é justamente essa parte de gerar uma ação no backend que não sei qual a maneira correta de implementar.

Comment: pronto 2 - pensei em usar esse agendador do SO mesmo, só estava na dúvida se era ou não uma boa abordagem.
Obg!

Comment: Você está utilizando MVC ou Web Forms? Esse algoritmo que roda do lado do servidor irá retornar que tipo de informações? Uma lista de objetos?

A rotina que você pretende agendar no lado do servidor não precisa retornar nada correto?

Comment: 1- Pretendo utilizar MVC no frontend.
2- Irá retornar uma string.
3- Não irá retornar nada, irá rodar e tomar ações internas.

Comment: Creio que a resposta acima sane sua dúvida, talvez você tenha alguma dúvida em relação a algum processo em específico, se for o caso sugiro você a abrir um tópico com a dúvida (caso não ache uma solução para seu problema)

Comment: Não esqueça de classificar a resposta positivamente, caso tenha lhe ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou sim Thiago, já classifiquei porém como sou novo no forum minha resposta não é contabilizada, grato !

Answer (score 0):

Pela descrição do seu problema você deveria usar uma biblioteca de agendamento, tal como o [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Com o próprio template de aplicação web mvc do visual studio você pode criar uma página com o botão run, chama via post um método no servidor que executará o job.
Além disso, você pode, no arranque da aplicação, criar o agendamento para correr o job nos horários pré determinados. Na própria documentação do hangfire há um exemplo para criar o job recorrente https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html